# Adding a new property to a control which opens a new form?

Tags: c#, activereports

We have a report designer project which uses Active Reports.
We want to use SubReport tool of the Active Reports.
Subreport control has a "report" property which fills the ActiveReport content of the Subreport.
Since we have a designer project and a SubReport tool,
I want to add a property to the SubReport control which opens a new form that enables user to choose a report from the list and load report into the SubReport control.

So how can I add a property to a control which opens a new windows form?

Here is how I set the properties:

```
public class SubReportProp
{
    private DataDynamics.ActiveReports.SubReport _SubReport;

    public SubReportProp(DataDynamics.ActiveReports.SubReport subReport, List<string> fieldCollection)
    {
        this._SubReport = subReport;

        if (fieldCollection != null && fieldCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            FieldVars._DataFields = fieldCollection;
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("X")]
    [Description("Kontrolün yatay konumunu getirir veya ayarlar.")]
    [Category("Konum")]
    public float X
    {
        get
        {
            return SharedProp.TrimFloatValue(ActiveReport.InchToCm(_SubReport.Location.X));
        }
        set
        {
            _SubReport.Location = new PointF(ActiveReport.CmToInch(value), _SubReport.Location.Y);
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Y")]
    [Description("Kontrolün dikey konumunu getirir veya ayarlar.")]
    [Category("Konum")]
    public float Y
    {
        get
        {
            return SharedProp.TrimFloatValue(ActiveReport.InchToCm(_SubReport.Location.Y));
        }
        set
        {
            _SubReport.Location = new PointF(_SubReport.Location.X, ActiveReport.CmToInch(value));
        }
    }
}
```

Like these x, y coordinates I also need to add another property which enables user to choose a report from a list and apply to _SubReport.Report

Comment: Please show me the code for SubReport Control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blogs.gcpowertools.co.in/2011/11/showcase-enhance-end-user-designer.html#more

I think you should have a look at this blog . It does exactly what you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for , but the sample project link is dead! I really need to see that sample project. Thanks for reply

Comment: You can download the sample from here:http://speedy.sh/56sMq/Enhanced-EndUserDesigner.zip

Comment: This is a great sample to me, but I want to ask for another favor if it is possible. In this example reports are saved either to a file or to memory. But in our project it is designed as the report layout is saved to Oracle. it is using OracleLob to save stream. If you know a sample uses Oracle to save report I would appreciate your suggesstions, thanks

Answer (score 1):

kubilay

Report layout can be saved to stream.  You can save this to the database as a blob/byte array.  You can also save the report in its xml format as text, if possible.  This is accomplished using the ActiveReport's SaveLayout API.

LoadLayout API can then be used to load this report back.